# iPad 2 can't update past iOS 9.3.5

Tags: ipad, software-update, hacking

My brother gave me his iPad 2. It doesn't update to iOS 10. How can I get it to allow me to download apps like Netflix. I know Apple cancelled the older version on iPhone and iPad to not be able to be updated, and I know if I didn't own app I can’t get past version, but there has to be a way or this iPad I have is basically a large camera you can FaceTime on.

Is there a way I can upgrade iOS on this iPad so I can install latest apps?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The iPad 2 was discontinued in 2014. The last version of iOS you can install is 9.3.5. It can't be updated past that. Your remaining option is to purchase a newer iPad.

Comment: So there's no where I can download 32 bit apps

Comment: How about downloading an old version from internet say Netflix would it be possible to do it direct with out iTunes or app store ??

Comment: @RafaelTorres It seems to me your real question is about something else here, rather than the version of iOS. Using Netflix as an example, if the latest version of Netflix doesn't support iOS 9.3.5 **and** no version is available that does support iOS 9.3.5, then that's a choice that Netflix has made. A developer can choose to allow older versions of their apps to be available on the App Store for those devices that aren't compatible with newer versions, and apps can support both 32-bit and 64-bit, they just can't be 32-bit only apps if published after 1 Feb 2015.

Comment: @RafaelTorres If you need to install a 32-bit only app that isn't currently installed on your device, then your only option is to re-install it from a backup you may have of the app (e.g. an old Time Machine backup that includes iOS apps downloaded via iTunes).

Comment: Ok so unless it was on app store before and you can install old version through apple app store nothing newly updated will work cause iOS isn't supporting anymore

Comment: If you bought the app before they releases an app version requiring a higher version of iOS, *and* if the vendor still makes the old version available, then you can still download it. One reason for the vendor not to do this are situations where the API on vendor side changed, rendering the old version of the app incompatible with the backend.

Answer (score 6):

This device can't update to iOS 10.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1893?locale=en_US) (see System Requirements at bottom):

**System Requirements**

- iPhone 5 or newer
- iPad 4th generation or newer
- iPad mini 2 or newer
- iPod touch (6th generation)